# Save OneToManyRelationship based on url input in Django

Tags: python, django, model

I have two database which are OneToManyRelationship as shown below.
I am preparing interface for Data to be uploaded.
I want to specify the project attribute in Data model by inputting the url of the Project path like `http://project/13`.
Does anyone know how I can construct the relationship from url input of parent data?

**Models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Data(models.Model):
    project=models.ForeignKey(project)
    csv=models.FileField(upload_to=dir_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If url in `Project` model sits in `project` field then you can do something like

```
# since project attribute is not unique, several ones can match so we pick first
project_object = Project.objects.filter(project=url).first()

if not project_object:
    # error cant find it

Data.objects.create(
    project=project_object,
    csv=...,
)
```